# How to parse the variables from a xml in php

Tags: php, xml

Suppose I get XML content from a URL in a PHP variable (e.g `$new`).

Below is an example of this XML content:

```
<getResult>
[{"abc": "123","xyz":"234","mno":"we4r5t"}]
</getResult>
```

When I do the parsing of XML content in php like:-

```
$xmlObj = simplexml_load_string($new);
error_log($xmlObj->getResult);
```

I get  `[{"abc": "123","xyz":"234","mno":"we4r5t"}]`

But I want to retrieve the inner content from the tag, e.g retrieve the value of only `abc` OR `xyz` OR `mno`.

How can do that?

Comment: The format of the inner content is called "JSON". (Which makes the XML wrapping somewhat pointless.)

Answer (score 0):

```
[{"abc": "123","xyz":"234","mno":"we4r5t"}]
```

That's not an XML-String it's a JSON object. You should parse it with json_decode !
http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

Your XML markup contains JSON-formatted data.

You need to perform JSON parsing on this string to extract the desired values, using [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-decode.php) for instance:

```
$json = json_decode($xmlObj);
$abc = $json[0]["abc"];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$xmlObj = simplexml_load_string($new);
$json = json_decode($xmlObj->getResult);
error_log($json[0]['abc']); // 123
```

I've used `$xmlObj->getResult` like in your answer and I assume you didn't post code with error.